# Encoding a page in UTF-8

Tags: java, html, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

What exactly is meant by encoding a page ?
I mean when someone says page is encoded in UTF-8 or some other format say EUC-KR, what does that mean? 
Is it referring to some server-side thing or client-side encoding ?
Is it the data which is rendered within the HTML OR to the HTML code which is rendered ?

Answer (score 0):

It's the data itself. The page's data is just a sequence of bits, and the encoding is what programs use to interpret the bits.

So I guess it's a server-side thing. The server sends the data, and based on the encoding (chosen by the server), the client can decide how to appropriately display it.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more. So from a browser perspective, is it referring to the data only i.e. may be html element attribute or value between the html tag itself. And encoding has nothing to do with the rendered code as such ?

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/